# Get powershell to control Internet Explorer and switch between 2 webpages

Tags: powershell

I want to have Internet Explorer to switch between 2 different webpages in an endless loop . The webpages is local files, that has to be viewed for 10 seconds before changing to next webpage. My code so far:

```
$ie = New-Object -Comobject 'InternetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Visible = $true

function IEWeb {
    $ie.navigate(file://D:\web\index.html)
    Start-sleep 10
    $ie.navigate(file://D:\web\index2.html)
    Start-sleep 10
}

while($true) {
    IEWeb
}
```

Everything is working until the second webpage has to be loaded.
Then I get an error message:

> Object is disconnected from it's clients. (Exception from HRESULT:0x800010108 (RPC_E_DISCONNECTED))

I have tried with global vars but still the same.
Can anyone give Me a hint of what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to produce your issue, but how about this?

```
function Navigate-Rotate {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string[]]$Url
        ,
        [Parameter()]
        [int]$SleepSeconds = 10

    )
    Process {
        $ie = New-Object -Comobject 'InternetExplorer.Application'
        $ie.Visible = $true
        while ($ie.Visible) {
            foreach ($uri in $Url) {
                if ($ie.Visible) {$ie.navigate2($uri)}
                Start-Sleep -Seconds $SleepSeconds
                if ($ie.Visible) {$ie.Stop()} #just incase anything's running which may interfere
            }
        }
    }
}
#Navigate-Rotate 'https://stackexchange.com','https://google.com'
Navigate-Rotate 'file:///D:/web/index.html', 'file:///D:/web/index2.html'
```

#### Notes

- I keep checking the value of `$ie.Visible`.  Should a user exit IE this ensures that my code won't try to use any of `$ie`'s methods.  NB: This value doesn't get set to false once closed; rather it ceases to exist; but that evaluates as falsey, so has the same effect.  There is a potential race condition, but it's minor / can't be avoided (or I don't know how to avoid it).
- I use `navigate2` instead of `navigate` since this method's a bit more flexible / there's no drawback.
- I use `$ie.Stop()` after loading each page to ensure that IE's not busy with other tasks when I try to navigate away from the page.  That should stop anything in the page from being able to block our attempt to navigate elsewhere.

#### Other Notes

- The change from a function to a cmdlet doesn't make much difference; it's just my preferred approach.
- Passing in a list of URLs to the function rather than hardcoding the 2 URLs means I can change the URLs easily (e.g. by reading in from a file), and I'm not restricted to 2 files/sites.
- Details of the methods and properties available in IE are listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752084(v=vs.85)

Apologies that I can't explain why you're seeing the issue you are; I just hope that this amended version avoids the issue you're seeing, and a few other potential issues you've not yet seen.

Comment: Funny.. Both scripts are working fine as along as they are used to access the web (google.com or so). But when I try with a local file both fails. My script go in error as described, and this is timing out.

Comment: Interesting; I tested with local files too and didn't see an issue (only let it run for a few iterations though)... What's in those html files; perhaps something in there will give us a clue (mine were simple pages with only static content).

Comment: There is nothing special in the webpages. A table with 4 collins and 1 row displaying the letters S,T,U,V that's it. A simple html4 webpage.

Comment: Is the code running on your local machine; or are you using PSRemoting / something like that?  Seems odd as the error relates to RPC (remote procedure call), which shouldn't be in play when everything's on the local machine.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/924432/fix-the-rpc-e-disconnected-error-code-may-be-returned-intermittently-w

Comment: Your script works!! I simply downloaded 2 pages from the web and saved them. Then it's working. I have to investigate My 2 original files. Something is wrong with the files. Thanx a lot for the help.